Loggers are not printing on OpenShift Console after deployment
I'm using Log4j - 2.22.1. version and wildfly- 31.0.1.Final
Loggers are printing in local But, while deploying it on openshift the loggers are not printing after the ear is deployed and i checked the logs that printed before deployment and i found a error like this
 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...

this are the dependencies using
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.22.1'
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.22.1'

Tried Adding this Dependency to the lib but didn't worked
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.21.1'

Tried adding log4j2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
        </Console> <File name="File" fileName="logs/app.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
    </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.jboss" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

and excluded wildfly logging subsystem in jboss-deployment but didn't worked
<exclude-subsystems>
  <subsystem name="logging"/>
</exclude-subsystems>


Have you checked your deployment to make sure it's including the log4j-core library? Also, is there a reason you need to use the log4j configuration? The same configuration would work in the logging subsystem. Then you wouldn't need to use log4j-core, just the log4j-api.

Yeah now i added only the log4j-api and checked in deployment also still in openshift loggers are not printing

You shouldn't even need to add the API to your deployment. WildFly contains a module for the API. You'd need to make sure you remove the jboss-deployment-structure.xml as well.

Tried that one too still same error

I'm not too sure what the issue would be. What version of JBoss EAP are you using?

INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 31.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 23.0.3.Final) starting
I am using full distribution of wildfly

Sorry, you said that. I'm really not too sure what the issue could be. If you don't exclude the logging subsystem and mark the log4j dependencies as <scope>provided</scope> it should work.

I have moved from log4j2 to slf4j this solved my issue

Strange, but I'm glad you got it solved.

Upgrade from log4j2 to slf4j-2.x
fixed the issue
